# How do I generate a timestamp and put it in a variable in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

How do I generate a timestamp and put it in a variable in jmeter?
So that the variable can be passed in the URL.

Answer (score 29):

Add the following function wheerever you want to send the Unix based timestamp:

```
${__time(,curTime)}
```

you can refer the value using `${curTime}` in later requests.

Example:

HTTP Sampler

[image]

in View Results Tree

[image]

---

You can use Function Helper Dialog (in Options), to generate the code:

[image]

Note: you can also save the value using `name of the variable` (second row), so later you can refer the same value.

Note: you can also format the time, based on your needs (first row).

Reference:

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time

Comment: Thanks Naveen - That is exactly what i am looking for.