# 2023-08-23T18:30:00.000Z how to create in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, timeshift

I want to create time date function for 2023-08-23T18:30:00.000Z. I tried to create 2023-08-23T18:30:00.000Z using time shift and also used time and date in jmeter but getting bad request.

I tried but getting bad request but dont know what is T in between date and time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I generate a timestamp and put it in a variable in jmeter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40803527/how-do-i-generate-a-timestamp-and-put-it-in-a-variable-in-jmeter), more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=timestamp+jmeter

Answer (score 0):

You can use timeShift or Time function to achieve this.

examples:-

`${__time(yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS'Z',)} //To get current date ${__timeShift(yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS'Z',,,,)} //to get current date ${__timeShift(yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS'Z',,-P365D,,)} //to get last year  ${__timeShift(yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS'Z',,-P3D,,)}  //to get 3 days back`